# Trigger Method in Activity when Notification is tapped

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

My app repeatedly loads data from a server. Among those data are messages.
Whenever new messages are loaded, the MainActivity is called on an Interface's callback method *onMessagesReceived(int numOfMessages)*.
The app has only one Activity and every screen is implemented as a Fragment. Switching of Fragments is managed by a dedicated *Navigator* class.

My problem is the handling of the user tapping on the Notification. When the user taps on the Notification, the message list should be shown.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MessageListener {
    private static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101010;
    private static final String EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES = "SHOW_MESSAGES";

    private Navigator mNavigator;

    @Override
    onMessagesReceived(int numOfMessages) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        testIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "testChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_notification)
                .setContentTitle("New messages!")
                .setContentText("You got " + numOfMessages + " new messages")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES)) {
            if (extras.getBoolean(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES)) {
                mNavigator.openMessageList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the MainActivity shows up, when the app is in background, but in *onResume*, the Bundle returns as *null*.
When the app is in the foreground, nothing happens at all.

I want to achieve on a click on the Notification:
- When the user is inside the app, the MessageList Fragment should be opened
- When the user is not inside the app, it should be started before opening the MessageList Fragment

Can someone give me a hint, how to proceed from here? Maybe using Intents isn't the right solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging on Intents and Notifications, I finally came up with a solution.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MessageListener {
    private static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101010;
    private static final String EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES = "SHOW_MESSAGES";

    private Navigator mNavigator;

    @Override
    onMessagesReceived(int numOfMessages) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        testIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES, true);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "testChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_notification)
                .setContentTitle("New messages!")
                .setContentText("You got " + numOfMessages + " new messages")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        this.setIntent(intetnt)

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES)) {
            if (extras.getBoolean(EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGES)) {
                mNavigator.openMessageList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I moved my code, reading the new Intent, to *onNewIntent*. This method gets called, when an Activity gets a new Intent and before *onResume*. This triggers regardless of the Activity being in the foreground or not. I also set this new Intent to be the Activities Intent with *setIntent*, otherwise the Intent that initialy started my Activity, is called by *getIntent()*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents just put some boolean extras in intent an just check the value in main activity if that extra value is true then call your method.

Comment: You're right, but in the end it doesn't matter, if I'm adding a boolean or a String as an extra. As long as I can't get the extra in case of the Activity already showing, I can't react on either extra.